# Edit MailMerge via OpenXml

Tags: c#, relationship, openxml, mailmerge

I have a `.docx` which includes a MailMerge, I need to change its source via code (C#). As library I'm using `OpenXml`. By Opening the docx as a zip file and looking for the paths, I have found that the link of the datasource is stored in two different places: in the `word/settings.xml` and in the `word/_rels/settings.xml.rels`.

To replace the fisrt:

```
var template = new MemoryStream(myDocxInByteArray);

using (var doc = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument.Open(template, true))
{
    var s = doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings;
    foreach (var els in s.ChildElements)
    {
        if (els is DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.MailMerge)
        {
            var mm = (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.MailMerge)els;

            mm.Query.Val = "SELECT * FROM " + myNewPath;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, however when the file is opened Word asks to load the file from the new path but also from the old one, since it is defined in the `word/_rels/settings.xml.rels`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/mailMergeSource" Target="oldPath" TargetMode="External"/>
</Relationships>
```

How can I find this object(`Relation`) in the `WordprocessingDocument`? Cannot find it...
Or is there another way to change it?

EDIT:

I created two different empty files with a different source and then opened with the OpenXml Productivity Tool in order to compare them. As I already have seen the differences are in the `word/settings.xml` and in the `word/_rels/settings.xml.rels`.

Comment: Try opening the document in Word, changing the data source, then saving this with a different name. Use the "Compare" feature in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to see the code it generates to change the one document into the other. FWIW, you'll probably need to  create a new Relationship ID (that will be stored in the rels file) and use it replace/delete the rId1 with that. That's usually how this kind of thing works with the Open XML SDK.

Comment: Ok, but how do i delete the old relationship? I cannot find it opening it with OpenXml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I came up with the following solution:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docInByteArray, isEditable: true))
{
    Settings settings = doc.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart.Settings;
    OpenXmlElement openXmlElement = null;
    foreach (OpenXmlElement element in settings.ChildElements)
    {
        if (element is MailMerge mailMerge)
        {
            mailMerge.Query.Val = "SELECT * FROM " + csvPath;
            mailMerge.DataSourceObject.Remove();
        }
        else if (element is AttachedTemplate)
        {
            openXmlElement = element;
        }
    }
    if (openXmlElement != null)
    {
        openXmlElement.Remove();
    }
    doc.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it this way, if you already have the appropriate rID (relationship ID) in the relevant part of the Settings Part XML. The approach I give relies on Linq.

But be aware that Word can store *two* Data Source file names in Settings.xml, with 2 corresponding relationships in settings.xml.rels. What's more, they both have the same Relationship type string. AIUI Word does not actually use the data file name in the ODSO ("Office Data Source Object") part of the MailMerge settings, but you should check.

One way to get to the old relationship is as follows (this requires Linq, as it stands):

```
// Get the Settings part
var settingsPart = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.DocumentSettingsPart;

// Create a MailMerge object and populate it with the existing data 
// (You do not have to do this - you could get the individual 
// elements/attributes from the part's XML)

var mailMerge = 
  new MailMerge(settingsPart.Settings.ChildElements.First<MailMerge>().OuterXml);

// Get the relationship

ReferenceRelationship oldRel 
  = settingsPart.ExternalRelationships.Where(
      Rel => Rel.Id == mailMerge.DataSourceReference.Id
    ).First();

/*
// to get the ODSO relationship, use the following, and to replace it, follow the pattern I give below for oldRel and newRel
ReferenceRelationship oldOdsoRel = 
  settingsPart.ExternalRelationships.Where(
    Rel => Rel.Id == mailMerge.DataSourceObject.SourceReference.Id
  ).First();
*/

// Delete the old Relationship (but notice that the oldRel object remains)

settingsPart.DeleteExternalRelationship(oldRel.Id);
var newRel = 
  settingsPart.AddExternalRelationship(
    oldRel.RelationshipType, 
    new Uri("your file path/name",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
    oldRel.Id);
```

Comment: I already tried to delete the entry from the external relationships, but `settingsPart.ExternalRelationships` is null.

Comment: If you are allowed to, please edit your original question to include code that you have used to get and delete the relationships. I also suggest that you try creating (in Word) a new document with a similar data source, and test your code against that.